# Errno::EINVAL in UsersController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

ruby version 2.2.4
rails version 5.0.0.1

gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'

Hello,

I want to  get this error when creating a user and I dont know why. I upload an avatar into the profile. After pressing the create-button the error below appears. Can you check please whats wrong with my program?

```
Errno::EINVAL (Invalid argument @ dir_s_mkdir - C:/Benutzer/Clemens/RubymineProjects/paperclip-example-master/public/system/users/:attachement):

app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.html.erb (10.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (4.0ms)
  Rendering C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (1.0ms)
  Rendered C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-5.0.0.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (1035.1ms)
```

**UserController**

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'Benutzer wurde erfolgreich erstellt.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :description, :avatar)
    end
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :avatar, 
    :path => ":rails_root/public/system/:class/:attachement/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
    :url => "/system/:class/:attachement/:id/:basename_:style.:extension",
    style: {
      :thumb    => ['100x100#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
      :preview  => ['480x480#',  :jpg, :quality => 70],
      :large    => ['600>',      :jpg, :quality => 70],
      :retina   => ['1200>',     :jpg, :quality => 30]
    },
    :convert_options => {
      :thumb    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
      :preview  => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
      :large    => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip',
      :retina   => '-set colorspace sRGB -strip -sharpen 0x0.5'
    }

  validates_attachment :avatar,
    :presence => true,
    :size => { :in => 0..10.megabytes },
    :content_type => { :content_type => /^image\/(jpeg|png|gif|tiff)$/ }

  validates :name,
    :presence => true,
    :uniqueness => true
end
```

Edit: here is the full trace:

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `mkdir'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:252:in `fu_mkdir'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:226:in `block (2 levels) in mkdir_p'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `reverse_each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:224:in `block in mkdir_p'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `each'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/fileutils.rb:210:in `mkdir_p'
paperclip (5.0.0) lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:38:in `block in flush_writes'
paperclip (5.0.0) lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:37:in `each'
paperclip (5.0.0) lib/paperclip/storage/filesystem.rb:37:in `flush_writes'
paperclip (5.0.0) lib/paperclip/attachment.rb:241:in `save'
paperclip (5.0.0) lib/paperclip/has_attached_file.rb:92:in `block in add_active_record_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:396:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:207:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:207:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `each'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:456:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_save_callbacks'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/callbacks.rb:298:in `create_or_update'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/persistence.rb:125:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/validations.rb:44:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:22:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block (2 levels) in save'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:395:in `block in with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `block in transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/transaction.rb:189:in `within_new_transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:232:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:211:in `transaction'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:392:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:319:in `block in save'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:334:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/transactions.rb:318:in `save'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/suppressor.rb:41:in `save'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:30:in `block in create'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/mime_responds.rb:195:in `respond_to'
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:29:in `create'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/basic_implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:188:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:126:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:506:in `block (2 levels) in compile'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:455:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:101:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:20:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:21:in `instrument'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:248:in `process_action'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:126:in `process'
actionview (5.0.0.1) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:190:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:262:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:50:in `dispatch'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:32:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:39:in `block in serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `each'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:26:in `serve'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:725:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:25:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/conditional_get.rb:38:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/head.rb:12:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:222:in `context'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:216:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:613:in `call'
activerecord (5.0.0.1) lib/active_record/migration.rb:552:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:38:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:97:in `__run_callbacks__'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:750:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:90:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:36:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:79:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:49:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:31:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:36:in `call_app'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `block in call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:70:in `tagged'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:24:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/method_override.rb:22:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (5.0.0.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:12:in `call'
actionpack (5.0.0.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:136:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:111:in `call'
railties (5.0.0.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:522:in `call'
rack (2.0.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:86:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.2.0/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: This may be a strange interaction between Windows and Rails. [A similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38381705/paperclip-does-not-show-images) was posted relatively recently, but received no answers. You may have some luck trying an earlier version of Paperclip or by running your app in a virtualized environment via Vagrant or Virtualbox.

Comment: Please check the permissions of your uploads folder and inner folders.

Comment: You guys are right. I have a permission problem with ImageMagick. When I try if ImageMagick works properly in cmd:  magick logo: logo.gif, I get Permission denied error. Hm....

Comment: Hm I have solved the permission problem with ImageMagick but I get still the same error. So this was not the problem. By the way I use gem 'paperclip', '~> 5.0.0.beta1'